# fc to loop through files to see if any files match

Tags: loops, batch-file

My goal is to compare say the contents of one txt file to the contents of all text files on a specific folder, if **ANY** txt files match then do one set of processes if none match then do another set.

I've tried doing the below:

```
@echo off
:main
fc "C:\Users\degibson\Desktop\test\*.txt" "C:\Users\degibson\Desktop\test2\temp1.txt" > NUL
if errorlevel 1 goto error

:next
echo do some important task
pause

:error
echo do some other important task
pause
```

Problem - This only works if ALL the files matched temp1.txt contents.

Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FOR` command to iterate all text files in the directory.  I would then suggest you use the `CALL` command instead of `GOTO` because `CALL` will return execution to the `FOR` command whereas the `GOTO` will break the `FOR` command execution. The execution returns to the `FOR` command by using the builtin `:EOF` label to end the current called process.  You could also use `EXIT /B`.

```
@ECHO OFF

:main
FOR %%G IN (C:\Users\degibson\Desktop\test\*.txt) DO (
    fc "%%G" "C:\Users\degibson\Desktop\test2\temp1.txt" >NUL
    if errorlevel 1 (
        CALL :error
    ) ELSE (
        CALL :next
    )
)
GOTO :EOF
:next
echo do some important task
pause
GOTO :EOF

:error
echo do some other important task
pause
GOTO :EOF
```